# How do I count unique users with patchy data?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have patchy data and I'm trying to count how many unique users I have. The email corresponds to user_ids, emails and devices. It's safe to assume that each user_id can have multiple emails and devices which will only correspond to that user_id. The data looks like this.

```
user_id      email         device
1            dave@ex.com   
             dave@ex.com   2w3e
             dave@ex.com   1q2w
                           1q2w
2                          3e4r
             bill@ex.com   3e4r
             bill@ex.com
             chris@ex.com
4
                           4r5t
```

Counting users is pretty tricky. The minimum number of distinct users I have is 3, however, I could have as many as five.

How should I count the numbers in either scenario?

Comment: If you normalize your data it should be simple as there will only be 1 row per unique user that will join to a user_emails table and user_devices table